# What is the derivative of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n,\quad -1<x<1$$

$$f'(x)=?$$

I think it is a Riemann sum as upper limit is infinity. I tried to modify the function so as to represent it through defined integral and solve but x to the power of n is confusing me. Can someone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Why not just take the derivative with respect to x?

Comment: It's easier than you think. Differentiate the series term by term, and see whether you recognize the result.

Comment: Please take the time to write out formulas using MathJax.  Pictures may not be legible, and secondly, they do not appear in searches.

Comment: That said, you say you "tried to modify the function so as to represent it through [a definite] integral" but I don't see any attempt to do so.  [To avoid having your questions closed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959), we recommend showing us what you've tried.  Shouldn't be too hard if you say you did try.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I take your feedback into consideration. Thank you for informing me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the function $f$ converges absolutely for $|x|<1$, the function $f$ is  differentiable in $(-1,1)$, and its derivative can be computed by differentiating term by term:
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}. 
$$
This function $f$ is an example of an [analytic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).

Answer (score 2):

For $x\in (-1,1) $,
$$f (x)=x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}+... $$
$f $ is differentiable at the open disc of convergence and

$$f'(x)=1+x+x^2+...=\frac {1}{1-x} $$